# Accessing list from function

Tags: python, list

I am writing a function where a user puts in text and a word and if the word is in the list, it returns the location of the word in the list.

```
list = ["hello", "goodbye", "name"]     

def fact(txt, my_list):
    text = txt.split()
    for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
        for j in range(0, len(text)):
            if(my_list[i] == text[i]):
                return my_list[i]

value = fact("hello, my name is", "name")
print(value)
```

However, this only seems to return none every time. Is there any particular reason it is not working?

Comment: Your indentation appears to be completely broken.

Comment: Please don't post code without proper indentation, especially python code.

Comment: Since in Python indentation is part of syntax, please make sur that your code is properly indented.

Comment: what is your expected output

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
  def f(text, search):
        if search in text.split():
            print('Word "{}" has been found @ index: {}'.format(search, text.split().index(search)))
```

**Output:**

```
data = 'hello world, my name is -e'
f(data, '-e')
```

> Word "-e" has been found @ index: 5

Comment: The function should *return* the index, not print it.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine

```
def getword(word, text):
    text = text.replace(',', '') # remove ',' by nothing
    tmp = text.split(' ')   
    if word in tmp:
        print("word: [%s] find at index %s in this text:[ %s]" % (word, tmp.index(word), text))
        return tmp.index(word) 
    else:
        print("Did not find [%s] in [%s]" % (word, text))
        return -1


word = "what"
text = "Hello, I am groot, what is your name"

index = getword(word, text)
```